# Facebook 4.0 on iOS, Current Access Token already hashed?

Tags: ios, node.js, facebook, sdk

Is the currentAccessToken received from Facebook already hashed? It is a issue regarding server side implementation. I believe the token is already hashed and that the server is doing it as well causing authentication issues.

iOS SDK, Facebook 4.x

Comment: What do you mean with hashed? The access token is a string that Facebook gives you and you should not modify

Comment: yes, you are correct WizKid. The token is already hashed. Was dealing with different clients at the time of this post. Moved way past that now, but thank you for your answer and your time.